# Creating a distance matrix from a matrix/list

Tags: python-3.x, euclidean-distance, distance-matrix

I have created a list from the input and from the list I have created a matrix also.
list-

```
('A', 'B', 3)
('A', 'D', 4)
('B', 'D', 4)
('B', 'H', 5)
('C', 'L', 2)
('D', 'F', 1)
('F', 'H', 3)
('G', 'H', 2)
('G', 'Y', 2)
('I', 'J', 6)
('I', 'K', 4)
```

matrix-

```
 ['A' 'B' '3']
 ['A' 'D' '4']
 ['B' 'D' '4']
 ['B' 'H' '5']
 ['C' 'L' '2']
 ['D' 'F' '1']
 ['F' 'H' '3']
 ['G' 'H' '2']
 ['G' 'Y' '2']
 ['I' 'J' '6']
 ['I' 'K' '4']
```

However I want to create a distance matrix from the above matrix or the list and then print the distance matrix. what will be the correct approach to implement it. In the above matrix the first 2 nodes represent the starting and ending node and the third one is the distance. I am ready to give any further clarification if required.A sample distance matrix is -

```
[[0, 10, 15, 20], 
 [10, 0, 35, 25],
 [15, 35, 0, 30], 
 [20, 25, 30, 0]]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the output represents? What are those values and why is it only 4x4?

Comment: Ok my output represnts a distance matrix and it is not limited to 4x4 . I will give an explanation for proper understanding.

Comment: Ok my output represents a distance matrix and it is not limited to 4x4 . I will give an explanation for proper understanding.  suppose I have 4 points A,B,C,D, . so the matrix[0][0] represents the distance between A,A which is obviously 0. Matrix[0][1] repesents the distance between A,B ,Matrix[0][2] repesents the distance between A,C. SimilarLy  matrix[1][0] represents the distance between B,A .matrix[1][1] represents the distance between B,B in this way. The number of rows will depend on the the number of nodes in the list.

Comment: and if you don't have a node from `A` to `H`, do you set the value to zero or do you find the distance of the shortest "path", for example `A --> B --> H`?

Comment: Make a simple and minimal example of input and expected output. I'm confused about first two element of tuples!  Should you just put the third element of tuple in right place of distance matrix? And please if you tried your self in python, put your code and its output respectively.

Comment: Hi Aziz,We can consider it to be zero if no direct path is there

Comment: I got your point. And distance matrix rows gonna refer to A, B, ... ? I mean in alphabetical order?

Comment: YES  both rows and columns will be like A,B,C and the matrix will show their distance.Its actually an adjacent matrix

Comment: Yes. It would be great if you show your attempt with code. did you try to solve it yourself?

Comment: No sayan atleast if u can guide me with the approach i can start doing the code because i didnot get any reference for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question can't be homework because it has a specific format like ("A" , "B" , 3) isn't orthonormal to me, so I decided to help you. But it's better to implement another idea for solving it to help yourself in coding. One approach is to assign a number to each char, then you can specify rows and columns of distance matrix with numbers that are associated with letters! for example impute 'A' to 1, 'B' to 2, and so on:

```
A┌ 0 3 0 ┐      1┌ 0 3 0 ┐
B| 3 0 0 |────► 2| 3 0 0 |
C└ 0 0 1 ┘      3└ 0 0 0 ┘
```

So in this example, 1 stands for "A" and so on. SO how this is going to help? Example: We have a pattern like `('A', 'B', 3)`, And I consider it as `(1, 2, 3)` then I can use the first two values of each tuple for index addressing in a distance matrix:

```
                                                       2
                                                    ┌─────────────┐
                                 Distance Matrix   1│  3   ...    │
('A', 'B', 3)─────► (1, 2, 3)    ───────────────►   │.     .      │
                                                    │.      .     │
                                                    │.       .    │
                                                    └─────────────┘
```

So first of all I'll create an input list as you mentioned. I'll name it `lis`:

```
lis = [('A', 'B', 3),
        ('A', 'D', 4),
        ('B', 'D', 4),
        ('B', 'H', 5),
        ('C', 'L', 2),
        ('D', 'F', 1),
        ('F', 'H', 3),
        ('G', 'H', 2),
        ('G', 'Y', 2),
        ('I', 'J', 6),
        ('I', 'K', 4)]
```

Then I detect unique letters in `lis` using `set` and `set.union`. consider we have letters in the first and second argument of each tuple:

```
items = set.union(set([item[0].upper() for item in lis]) , set([item[1].upper() for item in lis]))
```

Then I'll make a dictionary to assign values to each letter considering the order of English letters:

```
value = dict(zip(sorted(items), range(26)))
```

Then I'll create a zero matrix using `numpy.zeros`:

```
import numpy as np

dist_matrix = np.zeros((len(items) , len(items)))
```

The last step is assigning the third value of each tuple, to a related position in the distance matrix:

```
for i in range(len(lis)):

    # for Upper triangular 
    dist_matrix[value[lis[i][0]] , value[lis[i][1]]] = lis[i][2]
    # for lower triangular
    dist_matrix[value[lis[i][1]] , value[lis[i][0]]] = lis[i][2]

    """
    Example:
    [0 3 0]
    [3 0 0]
    [0 0 0]
    """

dist_matrix
```

This gives me:

```
array([[0., 3., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0.],
       [4., 4., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 5., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6., 4., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

### Appendix

All code at one glance:

```
import numpy as np

lis = [('A', 'B', 3),
        ('A', 'D', 4),
        ('B', 'D', 4),
        ('B', 'H', 5),
        ('C', 'L', 2),
        ('D', 'F', 1),
        ('F', 'H', 3),
        ('G', 'H', 2),
        ('G', 'Y', 2),
        ('I', 'J', 6),
        ('I', 'K', 4)]

items = set.union(set([item[0].upper() for item in lis]) , set([item[1].upper() for item in lis]))
value = dict(zip(sorted(items), range(26)))
dist_matrix = np.zeros((len(items) , len(items)))

for i in range(len(lis)):

    # for Upper triangular 
    dist_matrix[value[lis[i][0]] , value[lis[i][1]]] = lis[i][2]
    # for lower triangular
    dist_matrix[value[lis[i][1]] , value[lis[i][0]]] = lis[i][2]

    """
    Example:
    [0 3 0]
    [3 0 0]
    [0 0 0]
    """

dist_matrix
```

Comment: For arbitrary node names, better use `value = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(sorted(items))}` This would also allow names like AA AB, when there are more than 26 nodes.

Comment: @CarlosHorn Yes! He/She should consider this if He/She confront this kind of nodes name. But in examples that have been made in the question, there aren't names like that.

Comment: Hi Shayan the code is really helpful .Just in case i want to replace the nodes that are not connect directly by infinity in place of zero I feel I have to make some changes in this-                    line.dist_matrix = np.zeros((len(items) , len(items))). What change is required over here?

Comment: @user18129748 I didn't get your point exactly. Do you want to replace all zeroes in `dist_matrix` with the infinity sign?

Comment: Yes Shayan if that is possible I want to replace all zeroes with infinity

Comment: Check out https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html

Comment: @user18129748 add this command `dist_matrix[dist_matrix == 0] = np.inf` before(or even after) final stage. Please click on check ✅ mark button and accept the answer if my solution was exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not show any attempts, here some ideas to get you started.

1. Convert a character to a number, e.g. an index location:
   `ord('C') - ord('A')`
2. Creating a matrix:
   If you want to have a fixed size pre-allocated matrix, instead of lists in lists which have flexible size, the library `numpy` can help you. Then you can access fields and set values while looping through your data.
3. If you are really interested in analyzing a network, you could have a look into `networkx`.

Please take these ideas as a starting point and refine your question with more precise obstacles you encounter while trying to solve your problem.